# Preventing occasional flickering when transitioning between Angular views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-routing

I have written a simple app that saves a picture and some form fields into localstorage and present it on a confirmation page. I have added `ng-animate` to smooth most transitions. My issue is that flickering is occasionally happening. I have tried using `setTimeout` to prevent the issue, which sometimes works, but I am sure that this is not a best practice.

Here is my running code on plnkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/nQNcunJ0N5hYz1p5vf14?p=preview

Here is the relevant code:

```
var mcfApp = angular.module('mcfApp', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate','ui.mask','phoneNumberFilter']);

//creating routes
mcfApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'src/views/home.html',
            controller: 'homeCtrl'
        })
        .when('/form', {
            templateUrl: 'src/views/form.html',
            controller: 'formCtrl'
        })
        .when('/confirmation', {
            templateUrl: 'src/views/confirmation.html',
            controller: 'confirmationCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    }
]); 

//Home Controller
mcfApp.controller('homeCtrl', function () {
});

//Form Controller
mcfApp.controller('formCtrl', function ($scope, $location) {

    //Delaying loading in half a second to prevent flickering
    setTimeout(function(){
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.ready = true;
        });
    }, 1000);

    $scope.countryList = ["United States","Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua &amp; Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina","Botswana","Brazil","British Virgin Islands","Brunei","Bulgaria","Burkina Faso","Burundi","Cambodia","Cameroon","Canada","Cape Verde","Cayman Islands","Chad","Chile","China","Colombia","Congo","Cook Islands","Costa Rica","Cote D Ivoire","Croatia","Cruise Ship","Cuba","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Djibouti","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Ecuador","Egypt","El Salvador","Equatorial Guinea","Estonia","Ethiopia","Falkland Islands","Faroe Islands","Fiji","Finland","France","French Polynesia","French West Indies","Gabon","Gambia","Georgia","Germany","Ghana","Gibraltar","Greece","Greenland","Grenada","Guam","Guatemala","Guernsey","Guinea","Guinea Bissau","Guyana","Haiti","Honduras","Hong Kong","Hungary","Iceland","India","Indonesia","Iran","Iraq","Ireland","Isle of Man","Israel","Italy","Jamaica","Japan","Jersey","Jordan","Kazakhstan","Kenya","Kuwait","Kyrgyz Republic","Laos","Latvia","Lebanon","Lesotho","Liberia","Libya","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Macau","Macedonia","Madagascar","Malawi","Malaysia","Maldives","Mali","Malta","Mauritania","Mauritius","Mexico","Moldova","Monaco","Mongolia","Montenegro","Montserrat","Morocco","Mozambique","Namibia","Nepal","Netherlands","Netherlands Antilles","New Caledonia","New Zealand","Nicaragua","Niger","Nigeria","Norway","Oman","Pakistan","Palestine","Panama","Papua New Guinea","Paraguay","Peru","Philippines","Poland","Portugal","Puerto Rico","Qatar","Reunion","Romania","Russia","Rwanda","Saint Pierre &amp; Miquelon","Samoa","San Marino","Satellite","Saudi Arabia","Senegal","Serbia","Seychelles","Sierra Leone","Singapore","Slovakia","Slovenia","South Africa","South Korea","Spain","Sri Lanka","St Kitts &amp; Nevis","St Lucia","St Vincent","St. Lucia","Sudan","Suriname","Swaziland","Sweden","Switzerland","Syria","Taiwan","Tajikistan","Tanzania","Thailand","Timor L'Este","Togo","Tonga","Trinidad &amp; Tobago","Tunisia","Turkey","Turkmenistan","Turks &amp; Caicos","Uganda","Ukraine","United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom","Uruguay","Uzbekistan","Venezuela","Vietnam","Virgin Islands (US)","Yemen","Zambia","Zimbabwe"];
    $scope.stateList = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "District Of Columbia", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"];
    $scope.interests = window.localStorage['interests'] ? window.localStorage['interests'].split(",") : [];
    $scope.newsletter = window.localStorage['newsletter'] ? JSON.parse(window.localStorage['newsletter']) : false;
    $scope.firstName = window.localStorage['firstName'] || "";
    $scope.lastName = window.localStorage['lastName'] || "";
    $scope.age = window.localStorage['age'] || "";
    $scope.email = window.localStorage['email'] || "";
    $scope.phone = window.localStorage['phone'] || "";
    $scope.state = window.localStorage['state'] || "";
    $scope.country = window.localStorage['country'] || "";
    $scope.address = window.localStorage['address'] || "";
    $scope.address1 = window.localStorage['address1'] || "";
    $scope.address2 = window.localStorage['address2'] || "";
    $scope.profilePicture = window.localStorage['profilePicture'] || "";

    //Handles the close buttons inside individual interest items. Removes an interest from $scope.interests
    $scope.removeInterest = function (index) {
        var tmpArray = angular.copy($scope.interests);
        tmpArray.splice(index, 1);
        $scope.interests = tmpArray;
    }

    //Handles image uploads
    $scope.imageUpload = function(element){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = $scope.imageIsLoaded;
        reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);
    }

    //handles image onload and assigns the uploaded div to the correct element
    $scope.imageIsLoaded = function(e){
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.profilePicture = e.target.result;
            window.localStorage.setItem('profilePicture', $scope.profilePicture);
        });
    }

    //
    $scope.countryCheck = function(){
        if($scope.country !== "United States"){
            $scope.state = "";
        }
    }

    //handles form submission and path redirection
    $scope.formSubmit = function(){
        $scope.formSubmitted = true;
        for (var prop in $scope) {
            //getting only my custom objects
            if (prop.indexOf("$") !== 0 && String($scope[prop]).indexOf("function") === -1 ){
                window.localStorage.setItem(prop, $scope[prop]);
            }
        }
        $location.path('/confirmation');
    }

});

//Confirmation Controller
mcfApp.controller('confirmationCtrl', function ($scope, $location) {

    $scope.formSubmitted = window.localStorage['formSubmitted'] ? JSON.parse(window.localStorage['formSubmitted']) : false;
    $scope.interests = window.localStorage['interests'] ? window.localStorage['interests'].split(",") : [];
    $scope.newsletter = window.localStorage['newsletter'] ? JSON.parse(window.localStorage['newsletter']) : false;
    $scope.firstName = window.localStorage['firstName'];
    $scope.lastName = window.localStorage['lastName'];
    $scope.age = window.localStorage['age'] ? parseInt(window.localStorage['age']) : 0;
    $scope.email = window.localStorage['email'];
    $scope.phone = window.localStorage['phone'];
    $scope.state = window.localStorage['state'];
    $scope.country = window.localStorage['country'];
    $scope.address = window.localStorage['address'];
    $scope.address1 = window.localStorage['address1'];
    $scope.address2 = window.localStorage['address2'];
    $scope.profilePicture = window.localStorage['profilePicture'] || "";

    switch($scope.age) {
        case 1:
            $scope.ageGroup = "under the age of 20";
            break;
        case 2:
            $scope.ageGroup = "over the age of 20";
            break;
        case 3:
            $scope.ageGroup = "over the age of 30";
            break;
        case 4:
            $scope.ageGroup = "over the age of 45";
            break;
        default:
            $scope.ageGroup = "under a certain age";
            break;
    } 

    //Handles image uploads
    $scope.imageUpload = function(element){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = $scope.imageIsLoaded;
        reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);
    }

    //handles image onload and assigns the uploaded div to the correct element
    $scope.imageIsLoaded = function(e){
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.profilePicture = e.target.result;
            window.localStorage.setItem('profilePicture', $scope.profilePicture);
        });
    }

});

//Phone Number Filter
angular.module('phoneNumberFilter', []).filter('phoneNumber', function() {
    return function(input) {
        return input.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '($1) $2-$3');
    };
});
```

I'm using LESS, and here are the pieces relevant to these transitions:

```
.transition (@transition-string) {
    -webkit-transition: @transition-string;  
    -moz-transition:    @transition-string;
    -ms-transition:     @transition-string; 
    -o-transition:      @transition-string;
    transition:         @transition-string;
}

.ng-enter, .ng-hide-remove {
    .transition(0.5s linear opacity);
    opacity: 0;
}

.ng-enter.ng-enter-active, .ng-hide-remove-active {
    opacity: 1;
}

.ng-leave, .ng-hide-add {
    .transition(0.5s linear opacity);
    opacity:1;
}

.ng-leave.ng-leave-active, .ng-hide-add-active {
    opacity:0;
}

//Treating exceptions to the animation rules
.interest.ng-enter, .interest.ng-hide-remove {
    .transition(none);
    opacity: 1;
}

.interest.ng-leave, .interest.ng-hide-add {
    .transition(none);
    opacity: 0;
}

.mcf-view.ng-enter, .mcf-view.ng-hide-remove {
    .transition(1s linear opacity);
}

.mcf-view.ng-leave, .mcf-view.ng-hide-add {
    .transition(none);
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: I took out your `timeout` and `ng-show` attributes and I didn't see any flickering. Is there no way to reliably reproduce it?

Comment: oh, I just realized that it does not happen at plnkr at all! Could it possibly a problem with livereload on my grunt setting?

Comment: I don't know what that is, but yes, probably. Consider hosting your entire web app on plunkr.